# C# Manage call for multiple WCF Service on client side

Tags: c#, .net

I have a WCF Service(in C#) hosted on multiple IIS servers.
And I have a REST API(C#) accessing these service. 
I want that if WCF service on server1 failed to respond(or temporary down) then Rest API makes call to server2 for the same function and get data. if server2 also fails then check for server3 and so on...

I don't want to use GetMetaData for this.
Please help me out of this problem.

Thanks very much.!